# SMTP relay entries

Tags: email, postfix, mac-osx

By default, my mail server (Snow Leopard) contains an entry to only accept SMTP relays from `127.0.0.0/8`. However, when I attempt to check the option and save, the computer unchecks it. When I change the IP address to just `127.0.0.0`, I don't experience the unchecking problem. There are two possible solutions: either do you know what is causing the unchecking problem (or which configuration file should I edit to manually do this?), or is it acceptable to simply only have `127.0.0.0` as the IP address?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a 10.6 server handy to check with, but I'm pretty sure the default ("Accept SMTP..." option unchecked) setting *is* to allow relay from 127.0.0.0/8. Essentially, there are two different ways to get the same setting, you're entering one, and it's displaying the other.  You can verify this by looking in /etc/postfix/main.cf for a line starting with "mynetworks =".

Comment: I checked the option, changed `mynetworks` to `127.0.0.1/8`, and it works. Thanks for your help!